# Highstock Change tick interval on range selector change

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am unable to get the tickinterval to update in the following Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rarwarrar/5xgoqjst/4/

Currently this:

```
   xAxis: {
    events: {
    setExtremes: function(e) {
      if (e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "2Hour") {
         $('#chart').highcharts().xAxis[0].tickInterval= 2700000 //45 min
         $('#chart').highcharts().redraw()
       }
    }
    }
   },
```

Is not working.

For instance can the tick interval be set to every 45 minutes once '2hour' is clicked?

Comment: The first problem is that your function isn't running (add a `console.log()` to see). The `event` property should be `events`. But it still uses an interval of 15 minutes, and I don't know enough about highcharts to know why.

Comment: Updated to events, but as you pointed out, still doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tickPositioner function for changing your tick positions after you set your extremes. You can use Axis.update() for updating tickPositions of this axis:

```
   setExtremes: function(e) {
     if (e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "2Hour") {
       this.update({
         tickPositioner: function() {
           var positions = [],
             info = this.tickPositions.info;
           for (var x = this.dataMin; x <= this.dataMax; x += 45 * 60 * 1000) {
             positions.push(x);
           };
           positions.info = info;
           return positions;
         }
       }, false)
     }
   }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5xgoqjst/5/

You should be able to change your tickPositions on different ranges as well.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can, but that would be confusing to have text read "2hour" but actual time be 45 minutes. Why not add new button for this? In order for this to show there needs to be a minimum number of points but you can override with [`allButtonsEnabled`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.allButtonsEnabled). Here is what your `rangeSelector` could look like:

```
   rangeSelector: {
         allButtonsEnabled: true,
     buttons: [{
       type: 'hour',
       count: 2,
       text: '2Hour'
     }, {
       type: 'hour',
       count: 5,
       text: 'Week'
     }, {
       type: 'day',
       count: 1,
       text: '2Weeks'
     }, {
       type: 'minute',
       count: 45,
       text: '45 minutes'
     }],
     selected: 1,
     inputEnabled: false,
     buttonPosition: {
       x: 340
     },
     buttonSpacing: 10
   }
```

And here is a live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/5xgoqjst/2/) of it.

Comment: Thanks, but the confusing wording was just an arbitrary choice to express the problem. In truth it's because I need a specific range set each with their respective tick interval to go with it, the actual code has titles etc that make more sense.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Let me take another look.

Comment: I tried updated `event` to `events` and making function: `       xAxis: {
         events: {
           setExtremes: function(e) {
             if (e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "2Hour") {
               this.update({
                 tickInterval: 2700000
               });
               //$('#chart').highcharts().xAxis[0].tickInterval = 2700000 //45 min
             }
           }
         }
       },` but to no avail. Still odd time intervals for tick marks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help someone, I updated an existing [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/119/) ;-)

```
xAxis: {
  events: {
    setExtremes: function(e) {
      if (typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton) !== 'undefined') {
       // alert('count: ' + e.rangeSelectorButton.count + 'text: ' + e.rangeSelectorButton.text + ' type: ' + e.rangeSelectorButton.type);
        if (e.rangeSelectorButton.type === "week") {
          this.update({              
            tickInterval: 86400000, //1000*60*60*24 = 1 day
            minorTickInterval: 86400000
          }, false)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you will have to adapt it to your case of course.