# Highcharts/Highstock "Custom ticks" screwing xAxis up

Tags: reactjs, axis, highcharts

How do I prevent the function from screwing with the other axis labels? Or how do I set custom xaxis labels for rangeSelector All only?

I recently resolved a responsive error I was receiving here with the navigator in Highcharts, which could be found here:

> [custom ticks based on selected range from rangeSelector in Highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188433/custom-ticks-based-on-selected-range-from-rangeselector-in-highstock)

I was able to solve and fix the issue with the answer provided, but providing multiple/custom ticks are still an issue for me. The code I used to attempt at making custom ticks for the xAxis is below (**Guaranteed an issue with this code affecting the axis, I have debugged this with my basic knowledge**)

```
    events: {
      setExtremes: function(e) {
        if (e.trigger === "rangeSelectorButton" && e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "All") {
          var range = e.max - e.min;

          // ticks spaced by one day or one hour
          var ticksSpacing = range >= 86400 * 1000 ? 86400 : 3600;

          this.update({
              tickPositioner: function() {
                  var positions = [],
                  info = this.tickPositions.info;
                  for (var x = this.dataMin; x <= this.dataMax; x += ticksSpacing * 1000) { // Seconds * 1000 for ticks
                      positions.push(x);
                  };
                  positions.info = info;
                  return positions;
              }
          }, false);
        }
      }
    },
```

but the whole config I have for the xAxis is here

```
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      setExtremes: function(e) {
        if (e.trigger === "rangeSelectorButton" && e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "All") {
          var range = e.max - e.min;

          // ticks spaced by one day or one hour
          var ticksSpacing = range >= 86400 * 1000 ? 86400 : 3600;

          this.update({
              tickPositioner: function() {
                  var positions = [],
                  info = this.tickPositions.info;
                  for (var x = this.dataMin; x <= this.dataMax; x += ticksSpacing * 1000) { // Seconds * 1000 for ticks
                      positions.push(x);
                  };
                  positions.info = info;
                  return positions;
              }
          }, false);
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: 'Date (Timezone: PST)',
      style: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%b %e, %Y'
    },
    tickInterval: 1
  },
```

So you understand, here are images when an initial load; (selected: 6) in rangeSelector by default, which seems normal at first and not run the script function

[image]

What happens after selecting the All button manually from default load

[image]

To zoom in on how the xAxis labels are being affected, the dates are formatted to this now

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Linus apologize, I updated the question to, how do I prevent the function from screwing with the other axis labels? Or how do I set custom  xaxis labels for rangeSelector All only?